# LESS using variables

Tags: css, less

I am quite fresh to LESS. I am not sure where to look in the documentation for this or if it is possible.

I have container one, which has `height:auto`. it is a content container that will grow.

Can I have a second container that would be like - `container2:height = container1:height`.

So that the second container will become the same size as the container with height:auto.

This can be done with javascript of course but I am curious is this is something that can be done with LESS.

P.S.:If anyone wants to plug any good LESS tutorials/reading material, I would be happy to see it.

Comment: Is container2 inside container1 or is it entirely unlinked?

Comment: I am doing two columns inside of a container. I want one column to automatically receive the same height as the other column.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question about less then more a question about css.

To make a inner `div`element to fit the same height form the outer element without knowing (or given height) you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;

}
.inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

So you can be shure that the inner DIV has always the exact same sizes like the outer DIV

UPDATE:

When the DIV elements should not overlap each other you can do something like this:

```
.inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Now the second DIV has exact the same hight and is placed under the first one :)

Answer (score -1):

```
@height: 100px;
#container1{
  height: @height;
}
#container2{
  height: @height;
}
```

`@height: 100px;` I defined a variable with name is `height` and value is `100px` and I use it in the css underneath